# Using XPath in perl to read Mac Plist booleans

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, plist

I have a PLIST which when converted into XML has a fragment like this;

```
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>com.something.application</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>random.*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I 'm using perl XML::XPath to read this and can get the application-identifier easily using;

```
 my $app_id = $xp->findvalue('//key[text()="application-identifier"]/following-sibling::*[1]');
```

But I'm stuck reading the value for get-task-allow. For example, this does not seem to work;

```
my $gettask = $xp->findvalue('//key[text()="get-task-allow"]/following-sibling::*[1]');
```

Can anyone assist with the correct XPath search expression to use for reading the <false/> that is the value I wish to read for the get-task-allow key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a node

```
my ($gettask) = $xp->findnodes(
    '//key[text()="get-task-allow"]/following-sibling::*[1]');

say $gettask->nodeName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha ... so the following at least shows me I'm in  the right place;

```
$xp->findnodes_as_string('//key[text()="get-task-allow"]/following-sibling::*[1];
```